# Default Value set but Field not Being Updated

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

Just added a default value of 0 to my bit field in my SQL Server 2008 table.  Inserts are not defaulting to 0 and it is still putting a `NULL` in place...not sure why.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Messages] 
  ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Cars_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]
```

We are using the Entity Framework 4 to save/insert new records to this table.

Comment: What does your `INSERT` statement look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values only work when no value is specified for the column. If your insert statement supplies a null value for the IsDeleted column, then the null value will be stored instead of the default value. If this is the case you could either remove the column from the insert statement or wrap it in `isnull()`, with a default value of 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: awesome yea I had to MANUALLY update stupid EF to get it to match the DB changes.  Gay.  What kind of ORM is this?

Answer (score 0):

The IsDeleted property in you EF model is nullable?

I believe that you generated your entity model object from existing database. The IsDeleted is null able column. I think this is reason that you have got  nullable type for IsDeleted property.

please try on following...

- go to your .edmx model file.
- right-click on the Messages.IsDeleted
- select property
- you will see "Default value" on Properties panel
- You put 0 for as default value.

Comment: The delete is no longer nullable in the DB and I refreshed the EF model...still same issue.  I'll try your suggestion though thanks.